# How to point branch head in git to master?

Tags: git

I need to make commit, which is circled, linked to the head~1 of a master. In other words I want to remove all commits and branches, except one commit.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly:

- You want to discard the `batter-icons` branch.  That's easy:

  ```
  $ git branch -D batter-icons
  ```
- You want to *rebase* `ups-icons-support` on `master~1`.  So, do that:

  ```
  $ git checkout ups-icons-support
  $ git rebase master~1
  ```

Now you have:

```
           * ups-icons-support
  master * |
          \|
           * master~1
```

If your goal it to replace the old master branch, you could:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git reset --hard ups-icons-support
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two tasks:

- Remove the other branch.

You need the uppercase "d" because these commits are going to lose all references to get them.

```
git branch -D batter-icons
```

- Take only the last commit of ups-icons-support in master~1

This is done with git rebase --onto

```
git checkout ups-icons-support
git rebase --onto master~1 HEAD~1 ups-icons-support
```

1. --onto master~1 is where you want to start the rebase.
2. HEAD~1 is the first commit you want to rebase.
3. ups-icons-support is the end of the rebase.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answer, here is how I made it

**`git log --oneline --decorate --all --graph`**

`* dd9bda6 (origin/batter-icons, batter-icons) на всякий
* 16b9233 battery to primary
* cb61d3a icons 1
| * 3824a5e (origin/ups-icons-support, ups-icons-support) XFCE-powemanager-UPS-icons
| * 4c8ecae Reverted index.theme to original(as was after forking)
|/ 
* 7ca1226 (HEAD, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) 96 support
* 66c295a folders and index for panel folder
* c4ca2a7 1.3.1`

**`git branch -D batter-icons`**

**`git branch -D --remote origin/batter-icons`**

**`git checkout ups-icons-support`**

**`git rebase --onto master~1 HEAD~1 ups-icons-support`**

**`git branch -D --remote origin/master origin/ups-icons-support`**

**`git rebase --onto master~2 HEAD~1 ups-icons-support`**

**`git log --oneline --decorate --all --graph`**

`* c49c5e2 (ups-icons-support) XFCE-powemanager-UPS-icons
| * 7ca1226 (HEAD, master) 96 support
| * 66c295a folders and index for panel folder
|/ 
* c4ca2a7 1.3.1`